# Unable to download blender library files through subversion

Tags: svn, blender

I'm trying to download the library files for blender. I'm following the steps given in their web site to build blender for windows.  https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows/msvc/CMake

I'm having problem with "set up your repository" section where they tell to download 64 bit libraries using subversion.

Well the problem is that after downloading few files I get an error message

> svn: E120112: Error running context: APR does not understand this
>   error code

Also sometime I get an error message saying

> svn: E120106: ra_serf: The server sent a truncated HTTP response body.

Now I've no idea what these mean as I've no idea about subversion I just want to get blender source code and necessary file in my system so as to build it.

Is there any particular solution to this problem

Comment: The question is missing the main info -- what SVN client do you use and what is its version?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on two different computers. Using slikSVN 1.9.7 64bit on windows 10.